# Application slowness due to Tomcat waiting for readLatch

Tags: performance, tomcat7, ajp

we are getting issues reported by our clients that the application is slow at times, while checking the slow requests (using Glowroot) we could find quite a lot of threads getting stuck in `org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$KeyAttachment.awaitReadLatch` (we are using Tomcat 7), the stack trace is given below. Can someone give us a clue what could be wrong, as we are not able to find out the reason.

```
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpNioProcessor.process(AjpNioProcessor.java:184)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:149)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
org.xxx.doFilterInternal(xxx.java:58)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
org.yyy.doFilterInternal(yyy.java:22)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
org.zzz.doFilterInternal(zzz.java:43)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:72)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.obtainUsername(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:125)
org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParameter(RequestFacade.java:383)
org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParameter(Request.java:1148)
org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParameters(Request.java:3075)
org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.readPostBody(Request.java:3122)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:200)
org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:315)
org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.substract(ByteChunk.java:431)
org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:290)
org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(Request.java:422)
org.apache.coyote.ajp.AbstractAjpProcessor$SocketInputBuffer.doRead(AbstractAjpProcessor.java:1064)
org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpNioProcessor.receive(AjpNioProcessor.java:375)
org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpNioProcessor.readMessage(AjpNioProcessor.java:406)
org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpNioProcessor.read(AjpNioProcessor.java:314)
org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpNioProcessor.readSocket(AjpNioProcessor.java:342)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.read(NioSelectorPool.java:227)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.read(NioSelectorPool.java:246)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.read(NioBlockingSelector.java:174)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$KeyAttachment.awaitReadLatch(NioEndpoint.java:1554)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$KeyAttachment.awaitLatch(NioEndpoint.java:1552)
java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(CountDownLatch.java:277)
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.tryAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1328)
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1037)
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
```

Tomcat connector configuration:

```
 <Connector port="5011" protocol="org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpNioProtocol" redirectPort="8443" keepAliveTimeout="600000" connectionTimeout="300000" maxPostSize="20971520" maxThreads="1000" maxConnections="1000" processorCache="1000" acceptCount="500" acceptorThreadCount="3" />
```

Comment: Could you generate some thread dumps with `kill -SIGQUIT <JVM_PID>` The output will be written into `ls -l /proc/<JVM_PID>/fd/1`. Generate 2 thread dumps, one during the issue, and one when everything is fine. Another alternative is to use JMC (Java Mission Control) or any other profiler an record the performance during the performance drop and a bit after.

Comment: The thread you show is waiting for a semaphore/lock to be released. You need the stack trace of all threads to have full picture.